# What would be a norm on $\mathbb{Z}[1]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Set

$$\mathscr{O}=\{\sqrt{D}:D\equiv 2,3 \pmod 4 \text{ $D$ is square free}\} \cup \left\{\frac{1+\sqrt{D}}{2}:D\equiv 1 \pmod 4\text{ $D$ is square free}\right\}$$

and let $w\in\mathscr{O}$.

My text defines a norm on $\mathbb{Z}[w]$ as $N(a+wb)=(a+wb)(a+\overline{w}b)$ where $\overline{w}$ is $-\sqrt{D}$ if $D\equiv 2,3 \pmod 4$ and is $\frac{1-\sqrt{D}}{2}$ if $D\equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

However, this norm can be well-defined when $\sqrt{D}$ is irrational.

So under the above setting, $w$ is always irrational only except when $w=\frac{1+\sqrt{1}}{2}=1$.

When $w=1$, $\mathbb{Z}[w]=\mathbb{Z}$ and it is a Euclidean domain.

What would be a norm on $\mathbb{Z}$ which have some similarity with a norm defined in the first paragraph for an arbitrary $w$? Is it just $N(n)=|n|$?

Comment: Yes, it is just $|n|$.

Comment: @Crostul so do you mean one cannot solve pell's equation of the form $x^2 - y^2 = 1$ with these rings?

Comment: It is very easy to see that $x^2-y^2=1$ has only $(\pm 1, 0)$ as solution.

Comment: 1 is not square free.

Comment: @Andy I'm following wikipedia definition and $1$ is square free in this definition. (For any commutative ring $R$ and $r\in R$, any element $s$ such that $s^2|r$ is a unit.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the most natural generalization of the norm $N$ is the field norm; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_norm. The field norm $N$ agrees with the function $N$ defined in your text in all cases except for $w=1$, where the definition in the text is not well-defined, as an integer $n$ does not have a unique representation as a sum $n=a+1\cdot b$ with $a,b\in\Bbb Z$. In the case of $w=1$, the field norm would just be the identity map $N(n)=n$ on $\Bbb Z$.

Unlike the absolute value $|n|$, this definition of the norm $N(n)=n$ on $\Bbb Z$ is not a Euclidean norm even though $\Bbb Z$ is a Euclidean domain. The same can be said, however, for other examples also; for instance, in the case $w=2$, we are looking at $\Bbb Z[\sqrt 2]$, which is a Euclidean domain, but the field norm $N(a+b\sqrt 2)=(a+b\sqrt2)(a-b\sqrt2)=a^2-2b^2$ is not a Euclidean norm (because it takes negative values); in this case, again the absolute value of the field norm, $|a^2-2b^2|$, is a Euclidean norm. However, it doesn't always work out this way; for example, $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{67}]$ is a Euclidean domain where the absolute value of its field norm is not a Euclidean norm (see http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02567617).

Comment: Thank you for kind explanation.